# Find single value from multiple values in single array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, arraylist, contains

I have a single array having multiple values in that as shown in code below.

```
tempstraindatasource

tempstraindatasource[0] = {
A = "0",
B = "1",
C = "2",
D = "3"
}

tempstraindatasource[1] = {
A = "4",
B = "5",
C = "6",
D = "7"
```

and so on like wise I have many data exist in single array
}

I want to do one procedure that finds the data are consist or not in single line like I want to find Species having name "A" = "0" or any value "B" = "0" or "C" = "0"! How can I do it in single line? Please some one help me to do this.

Thanks in advance and appreciate as well.

Comment: Can you please replace the image with code? It is much easier for people to try and reconstruct your issue copying and pasting code, rather than reading it from an image.

Comment: _Please some one help me to do this it's urgent._ Sure, we're here to help you. But, you should first see **[ask]** and **[mcve]**

Comment: please add what you like to search for and the wanted result.

Comment: I have updated the question please see it again @NinaScholz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for the array and check if any of the properties have the value, you need with [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), and push the index then to the result array.

```js
var data = [{ a: 0, b: 1, c: 2, d: 3 }, { a: 4, b: 5, c: 6, d: 7 }],
    indices = [];

data.forEach(function (a, i) {
    Object.keys(a).some(function (k) {
        return a[k] === 0;
    }) && indices.push(i);
});

console.log(indices);
```

Comment: Can I get index like a[k].index as return?

Comment: ohhh get it and thanks a lot @NinaScholz for such an awesome logic helps me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in comments your question needs editing (or better a total rewrite) but I think what you need is this

```js
var fruits = [{name: 'banana', cost: 5}, {name: 'apple', cost:2}];

var filteredArray = fruits.map(function(fruit, index){
  fruit.index = index;
  return fruit;
}).filter(function(fruit){
  return fruit.name === 'banana';
});

document.write(JSON.stringify(filteredArray));
```

Comment: Yes that is what I wanted but I need index of that array can I get it? Please update snippet if you can for index.

Comment: Thank you @Almis thank you so much very appreciated but I got already from NinaScholz still thanks for spend your precious time for this.